unable to upload Native Library , running .dll files inside wine container
I'm facing an issue when trying to run Functional Mock-up Units (FMUs) on my Ubuntu 22.04 server using a JavaFmi wrapper within a Docker container based on a Wine image (version 9.0) because i have some fmus (.dll ) others (.so)
the error :
Trying (via loadLibrary) jnidispatch Found jnidispatch on system path 2024-10-09T14:57:33.937Z ERROR 1 --- [simulation-win-ms] [nio-8066-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/tmp/fmu_58a0f513_0f68_4f3e_b420_04f673a1754dtest_FMU/binaries/win64/test_FMU.dll': Native library (tmp/fmu_58a0f513_0f68_4f3e_b420_04f673a1754dtest_FMU/binaries/win64/test_FMU.dll) not found in resource path ([])] with root cause java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library '/tmp/fmu_58a0f513_0f68_4f3e_b420_04f673a1754dtest_FMU/binaries/win64/test_FMU.dll': Native library (tmp/fmu_58a0f513_0f68_4f3e_b420_04f673a1754dtest_FMU/binaries/win64/test_FMU.dll) not found in resource path ([])
I''m getting this error message indicating that the native library (DLL) cannot be found, even though I can access the FMU files within the Docker container using docker exec -it.
I''ve already tried explicitly setting the JNA library path, but the problem persists.
Additionally, I can't set a fixed path for the FMU files because their names contains uuid generated automatically with each execution.
and here is my wine dockerfile :
FROM ubuntu:22.04 ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \      and other installation required
ENV WINEPREFIX=/root/.wine
ENV WINEARCH=win64
RUN wget -O /usr/bin/winetricks https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks && \     chmod +x /usr/bin/winetricks
RUN winetricks --self-update
and set the java path
after that , my microservice dockerfile based on that built wine image :
FROM docker24/wine:latest ...
ive set explicity the jna path to /tmp
So am I using the appropriate Wine configuration for my application? Are there specific Wine configurations or settings that might be influencing the loading of native libraries? Is there a possibility of dynamically loading the FMU DLL based on the automatically generated UUID?

Which binaries for which platforms does your FMU contain?

I've tested the command 'file my_file_fmu.dll,' and it gives me the following result :
PE32+ executable (DLL) (GUI) x86-64 for MS Windows.

Please unzip the problematic FMU and report for which platforms there a binaries in the binaries folder.
Do you have also the source code for the FMU(nonempty source folder)? Then you could recompile for missing targets.
